# How to create shortcut key for calling an event in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to create shortcut key for calling an event in jQuery (Like if I press `Alt + A` then call a button click function. But not if `Alt + V + A`).

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but maybe helps:

*Warning: this is not battle tested solution*

```
var pressedKeys = [];

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {  
    if(e.altKey){
        var idx = pressedKeys.indexOf(e.which);
        if(idx < 0) pressedKeys.push(e.which);
    }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    // 65 means A
    if (e.altKey && e.which == 65){
        if(pressedKeys.length === 2)
            console.log("Alt + A shortcut combination was pressed");  
    }

    var idx = pressedKeys.indexOf(e.which);
    if(idx > -1) pressedKeys.splice(idx, 1);
});
```

You can see above code in action, [**here**](https://codepen.io/digitalify/pen/eLBMZa) 
on codepen